# How do I create a code snippet for XML (VSCode) that contains quotes

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I tried searching the documentation for VSCode and couldn't find the answer. I want to write a code snippet for an XML header in VSCode, but my snippet includes quotes which are causing an issue. How would I format this code snippet?

```
"body": ["<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>",]
```

Comment: you need to ESCAPE the `"` characters

Comment: Is that with \\

Comment: Just a single backslash is sufficient.

Comment: FYI, vscode-xml now provides that very snippet, that shows up when opening a bracket on the 1st line of an XML document https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j5YA.png